# How to see BACnet scrape data on volttron.log

Tags: volttron

Can someone give me a tip on how see the BACnet scrape data on the VOLTTRON .log?

Would this have anything to do with the `log level`? Maybe I just cant see any data because of incorrect log levels? Any tips setting the log level appropriate greatly appreciated.

`vctl config get platform.driver devices/201201`
returns this:

```
{
  "driver_config": {
    "device_address": "12345:2",
    "device_id": 201201
  },
  "driver_type": "bacnet",
  "interval": 60,
  "registry_config": "config://registry_configs/201201.csv"
}
```

Running:
`vctl config get platform.driver registry_configs/201201.csv`

Looks good I can see all of the device points that were discovered:

```
  {
    "Reference Point Name": "Oat",
    "Volttron Point Name": "Oat",
    "Units": "degreesFahrenheit",
    "Unit Details": "",
    "BACnet Object Type": "analogValue",
    "Property": "presentValue",
    "Writable": "FALSE",
    "Index": "301",
    "Write Priority": "",
    "Notes": ""
  },
  {
    "Reference Point Name": "RmTmpSpt",
    "Volttron Point Name": "RmTmpSpt",
    "Units": "degreesFahrenheit",
    "Unit Details": "",
    "BACnet Object Type": "analogValue",
    "Property": "presentValue",
    "Writable": "FALSE",
    "Index": "302",
    "Write Priority": "",
    "Notes": ""
  },
  {
    "Reference Point Name": "RmTmp",
    "Volttron Point Name": "RmTmp",
    "Units": "degreesFahrenheit",
    "Unit Details": "",
    "BACnet Object Type": "analogValue",
    "Property": "presentValue",
    "Writable": "FALSE",
    "Index": "300",
    "Write Priority": "",
    "Notes": ""
  }
```

Running a `vctl status` and even restarting UUID `a` and `4` doesnt seem to do anything.

```
UUID AGENT                    IDENTITY              TAG             STATUS          HEALTH
a bacnet_proxyagent-0.5    platform.bacnet_proxy proxy           running [73753] GOOD
4 platform_driveragent-4.0 platform.driver       platform_driver running [73754] GOOD
6 simplewebagent-0.1       webagent              simpleWebAgent
```

Also the `BACpypes.ini` has the proper ID address set for the IP address of the computer running VOLTTRON.

Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generall you won't want all of the data going through the message bus in the log as that will make your log huge and fill up the system.

However, if you install and start a listener agent you will get that behaviour.  A listener agent will write to the log everything that goes through the message bus.  It is located in the examples/ListenerAgent from the volttron repository.